# how to rename the images taken from camera through our app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, camera, rename

I want to know how the iphone take the picture from camera through xcode?
and how it is stored ?,How to rename it? And how to delete it after our work completion?
please tell me the details about the UIPickerView also...
Thank You,
anand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UIImagePickerController` to take picture from camera. You can refer 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

You can get an `UIImage` from the imagepicker which u can use according to your needs

Comment: hi may i know how the iphone  taken photo after 3 secs when camera open?

Answer (score 0):

@Anand for your camera issue take help from the 7KV7 suggest link that is the best one from the apples developer document
Take image from camera and then do it what you want to do with that image.

As far as `UIPickerView` is concerned refer **[UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview)** and also have a look at **[iPhone SDK Tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20150302061136/http://www.bogotobogo.com/XcodeSDK-Chapter6.html)**

For `pickerview` you have to call different delegate methods and those methods are mentioned in the tutorial i had shared you above.

Comment: hi may i know how the iphone taken photo after 3 secs when camera open? and how to rename it?