# Is there a way select a specific image for use in a UITable iOS?

Tags: ios6, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UITable, and I like to add an image in the detail view for a cell. I can handle the selection for any image from the camera roll or from the camera:

```
cell.imageView.image = someImage;
```

But how do I define a specific image - in the case above: "someImage", so that the next time the app is run, the correct image is shown for each item.

UPDATE. This is the code I'm using to snap/select an image..

```
- (IBAction)btnTakePicture_Clicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Image from..." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Camera", @"Image Gallary", nil];
    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
    actionSheet.alpha=0.90;
    actionSheet.tag = 1;
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    switch (actionSheet.tag)
    {
        case 1:
            switch (buttonIndex)
        {
            case 0:
            {
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR

                UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ooops" message:@"Camera not available." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];

#elif TARGET_OS_IPHONE

                UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
                picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                picker.delegate = self;
                //picker.allowsEditing = YES;
                [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];


#endif
            }
                break;
            case 1:
            {
                UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
                picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
                picker.delegate = self;
                [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
            }
                break;
        }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}


-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"],1);
    imgPicture.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:dataImage];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

UPDATE 2. With the help from people below, I think this solution will work for me:

```
- (IBAction)photoLibraryAction:(id)sender
{   
    int c = self.capturedImages.count;
    for (int i=0; i < c; i++ ){
        if (self.imageView.tag == cellTag) {
            NSLog(@"found it");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"can't find it");
    }
    }
}


 if ([self.capturedImages count] == 1)
        {
            // we took a single shot
            [self.imageView setImage:[self.capturedImages objectAtIndex:0]];
          [self.imageView setTag:myTag];
        }
```

Comment: Hi, is that image going to change for each cell or it is the same image for all the cells like you want to use an icon some where in each cell?

Comment: Hi Maziyar, it is a different image for each cell.

Comment: One more question, are you going to fetch the images from internet or it is a local photos and in this case it is not a dynamic table (like parsing an XML file and try to update the table along data and photo's url)?

Comment: I was just thinking that. The images are going to be local (to the device and/or iCloud), and I guess I'm struggling to find the image name. Can I attach a tag when I take the image? (I have an app out there that does use an XML parse file, but that's easy as I know the image names.

Comment: OK I know you can rename the photos when you take them by camera by using UIImagePickerController, It is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256020/how-to-rename-the-images-taken-from-camera-through-our-app. But keep that in mind if you want to have the same situation when user closes the app and re open it again, you should consider a data persistence strategy. Whether it's a SQLite or a simple plist to just be used as a dictionary that you won't miss the records. Each time you update the table, you know each cell has a title and a Photo's address (local or on the iCloud).

Comment: hmm. I've gone thru the referenced SO question. I cannot figure how to set any kind of tag so that I can reference images. It would be perfect to know that. Then I can store the reference in the app's model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do in this way.

```
@interface CustomClassCell : UITableViewCell
  @property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *HomePicture;
@end

@interface CustomClass : NSObject
   @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *PicPath;
@end


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath      
{
   CustomClassCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomClassCellIdentifer"];
   id object = [self.tableData  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   CustomClass *myObject = (CustomClass*)object;
   cell.HomePicture.image = [UIImage imageNamed:myObject.PicPath];
   return cell;
}
```

Comment: I am still missing a bit I think.. The process is that a user picks or takes an image. I can do this ok through the app.  How do I tell the app what picture the user has taken? Maybe I'm missing that point in your example.

Comment: oh yeah that is the case. Can you show me the code wich you are using to take pic ? I think you should put that image inside the DataArray and then call the [tableview reloadData] function.

Comment: I've amended the original question to show the snap/select code.. Thanks for helping..

Comment: Muhammad, I'm marking your answer as the solution, as it was the basis for figuring this out. I've amended my code to show a solution that I think is working :)

Comment: I came across this tutorial, with sample code, that is helping me quite a bit. It's more than I asked in my question, but it may also help others: http://tinyurl.com/7t64e7d

Comment: well thats great its working and you are always welcome. thanks